# Can we convert a character array to int array?

Tags: arrays, c, string, casting

I was solving this question. The problem statement says I have to print the difference between the sum of odd indexed integers and even indexed integers. For example:

Input: 4567

Expected Output: 2

I wrote this code but after that taking the input it is neither printing anything nor exiting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{
    char num[100];
    int i,j,len = 0;
    int diff = 0;
    
    int s_even =0,s_odd = 0;

    scanf("%s",num);
    len = strlen(num);
    
    for(i=0;i<len;i+2)
    {
        s_even+=int(num[i]);
        s_odd+= int(num[i+1]);
    }
    diff = s_even - s_odd;
    printf("%d",diff);
    return 0;
}
```

I was curious if the char string will do arithmetic addition or not. And, can I typecast it as I have done in last **for** loop? Please suggest me.

Thank you

Comment: `i+2` is a bug which adds 2 to `i` and then throws away the result (and does not increment `i` in the process). Did you mean `i+=2`

Comment: a `char[]` array *is* an integer array. You don't need to cast, the values will be promoted to `int`. Also you could simplify by using a single sum: add the even elements and subtract the odd elements.

Comment: A debugger would have helped you figure this out.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it helped @drescherjm

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::vector`, `std::array`, iterators, `std::cout` and `std::cin`.  In C, you can have a variable named `class`.  Please update you language tags to represent the language you are programming in.

Comment: @Shaziya Hasan The presented code is neither a C code nor a C++ code.:)

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string` for text and not character arrays.  Character arrays can underflow or overflow.  If the terminating nul character is missing, then undefined behavior can occur (such as searching the entire memory for the length of a string).

Comment: Thank you, I got my answer. By the way, I was asking in C.

Comment: You should specify the field width when using `scanf`, so your array does not overflow.

Comment: Also, in your loop, when `i` == `len-1`, you'll be accessing beyond your array.

Comment: @ShaziyaHasan, if you are asking in C, get rid of the C++ tag.

Comment: If you restrict the program to using ASCII, you don't need the `int` cast.  The character `'0'` is even as well as `'2'`.  Likewise, `'1`' is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're not actually increasing i withing your for loop: replace "i+2" with "i+=2"

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the presented code is neither a C code nor a C++ code.

For example in C++ you should use headers looking like

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
```

On the other hand, in C there is no functional casting like this

```
s_even+=int(num[i]);
```

that moreover does not make a great sense.

In this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<len;i+2)
```

the variable `i` is not being changed. So the loop can be infinite.

Also there is no need to call the string function `strlen`.

A C program can look at least the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char num[100];
    num[0] = '\0';
    
    scanf( "%99s", num );

    int s_even = 0, s_odd = 0;
    
    for( size_t i = 0; num[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if ( '0' <= num[i] && num[i] <= '9' )
        {
            if ( i % 2 == 0 )
            {
                s_even += num[i] - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                s_odd += num[i] - '0';
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "The difference is equal to %d\n", s_odd - s_even );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the sequence of characters

```
4567
```

then the program output will look like

```
The difference is equal to 2
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` is still valid C++.

Comment: @Eugene Nevertheless in C++ you should use C headers starting with 'c'.